# Converting a Index & Match & Offset function to work with userform

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I have a working VBA code here:

```
Evaluate("INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(J5,B$6:B$72,0))") = Change_Pool.Value
```

What it does, is takes a index and matches it with a userform linked cell (J5).

---

What I want it to do is:
1. Make the VBA code use the combobox on the userform (Edit_pool.Change_Pool) instead of the linked cell. ie:

```
Evaluate("INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(  *Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value*  ,B$6:B$72,0))")
```

2. Then I want it to offset the result down a cell.
   So It would look like

   Offset ("INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(  *Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value*  ,B$6:B$72,0))") 1

or something ^^

Comment: You want to invoke `Worksheet.Evaluate`, not `Application.Evaluate` - otherwise `Evaluate` is operating in the context of whatever worksheet is currently active... and you *don't* want to be activating sheets just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match text values, try...

```
Evaluate("OFFSET(INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(""" & Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value & """,B$6:B$72,0)),1,0)") = Change_Pool.Value
```

To match numerical values, try...

```
Evaluate("OFFSET(INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(" & Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value & ",B$6:B$72,0)),1,0)") = Change_Pool.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
Evaluate("INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(" & Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value & ",B$6:B$72,0))")
```

Note if your value is not numeric you'll need to add quotes around it:

```
Evaluate("INDEX(A$6:A$72,MATCH(""" & Edit_pool.Change_Pool.value & """,B$6:B$72,0))")
```